# angular 2 UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.4.8

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

i am a new in angularjs2 and i want to implement server side datatable in my app so for this purpose i have use

`npm install --save ng2-smart-table library`

but it's give error like

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.4.8
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.4.8
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.4.8
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@2.4.8
+-- ng2-smart-table@0.5.3-0 
| `-- ng2-completer@1.2.0 
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.2.0
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.5.3",
    "angular2-flash-messages": "^1.0.5",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^0.5.3-0",
    "ngx-uploader": "^2.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.54",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

so how can i solve this ? i don't want to reduce my app version.

If you have any better way or library for implement serverside  datatable then please suggest me. in my app i have use php as backend

Comment: Can you add package.json?

Comment: `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY` is just warning while installation is safe to proceed

Comment: **@anshuVersatile** did you means it's just Waring  and not effected in implementation ?

Comment: **@suraj** Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by installing the packages:

```
npm install @angular/common@2.4.8 @angular/compiler@2.4.8 @angular/core@2.4.8 @angular/forms@2.4.8 rxjs@5.2.0 --save
```

Or if you use yarn.

```
yarn add @angular/common@2.4.8 @angular/compiler@2.4.8 @angular/core@2.4.8 @angular/forms@2.4.8 rxjs@5.2.0 --save
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post with your package.json as Suraj asked, please?